# Timestables from the first input to the last input using nested for loops in java

Tags: java, loops

So I want to create a timetable in java from **n1 to n4**, so two numbers are inputted in the scanner.

For example

Sample input:

```
5
7
```

And then the output should be the timetables from 5 to **n4** until 7

```
5 * 1 = 5
5 * 2 = 10
5 * 3 = 15
5 * 4 = 20
6 * 1 = 6
6 * 2 = 12
6 * 3 = 18
6 * 4 = 24
7 * 1 = 7
7 * 2 = 14
7 * 3 = 21
7 * 4 = 28
```

**See how the middle number is only till 4 and outputs timetable from the first to the last number**

**This has to be done with nested for loops only with only one print statement**

This is what I tried but my output was:

My output:

```
It displays the results up to 4 but for each one, it does it 8 times, and 
only for 5
```

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Timestables {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n1 = keyboard.nextInt();
        int n2 = keyboard.nextInt();
        for (int y = 1; y <= 4; y++) {
            for (int x = n1; x <= n2; x++) {
                int result = n1 * y;
                System.out.println(n1 + "*" + y + "=" + result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The variable n1 represents the first number, and n2 represents the last number**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bounds of the outer loop should be from `n1` to `n2`, inclusive on both ends.  The bounds of the inner loop should be from 1 to 4:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
int n1 = keyboard.nextInt();
int n2 = keyboard.nextInt();
    for (int i=n1; i <= n2; ++i) {
        for (int j=1; j <= 4; ++j) {
            int result = i*j;
            System.out.println(i + " * " + j + " = " + result);
        }
    }
}
```

This prints, using inputs of `n1=5` and `n2=7`:

```
5 * 1 = 5
5 * 2 = 10
5 * 3 = 15
5 * 4 = 20
6 * 1 = 6
6 * 2 = 12
6 * 3 = 18
6 * 4 = 24
7 * 1 = 7
7 * 2 = 14
7 * 3 = 21
7 * 4 = 28
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to achieve this

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class A {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number1 = keyboard.nextInt();
        int number2 = keyboard.nextInt();
        do {
            int count = 1;
            while (count <= 4) {
                System.out.println(number1 + " * " + count + " = " + number1 * count++);
            }
            number1++;
        } while (number1 <= number2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Timestables {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n1 = keyboard.nextInt();
        int n2 = keyboard.nextInt();
        for (int i = n1; i <= n2; i++) { // from n1 = 5 to n2 = 7
            for (int j = 1; j <= 4; j++) { // multiplication from 1 to 4
                System.out.println(i + "*" + j + "=" + i * j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```